# display message of the pop up box through vba

Tags: excel, vba

Sub DisplayRedColorCount()

```
Dim Rng As Range

Dim CountRange As Range

Dim ColorRange As Range

Dim xBackColor As Long

On Error Resume Next

xTitleId = "Test"

Set CountRange = Application.Selection

Set CountRange = Application.InputBox("Count Range :", xTitleId, "A2:A500", Type:=8)

Set ColorRange = Application.InputBox("Color Range(single cell):", xTitleId, "K9", Type:=8)

Set ColorRange = ColorRange.Range("A1")

xReturn = 0
```

For Each Rng In CountRange

```
    qqq = Rng.Value

    xxx = Rng.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color

    If Rng.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color = ColorRange.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color Then
        xBackColor = xBackColor + 1
    End If

Next

MsgBox "Count of Colors is " & xBackColor

Range("j9") = " " & xBackColor
```

End Sub

The above code has worked now. So, I have created three modules to run for three colours. Red, Green, Yellow. I can extract the numbers of cell in colours.

Now, i would like to create a macro for conditional formatting. I mean conditional formatting to find duplicates in columns A,B,C,D,E.

Not by going into conditional formatting option but using macro and execute that macro using a button.

So, i just need your expertise on how to create a macro to locate duplicate values from 5 columns.

Thank you for your time.

Kind regards.
Thank you.

Comment: What should the next cell be? H15? I14? Something else? What is the logic behind "another cell"?

Comment: Provide your code attempt and explain what part is not working (Error? If so, which line?  Not working as expected? Then show us the expected result).

Comment: thank you for your prompt responses.

Comment: Please [edit] your question with the relevant code, instead of posting code in comments.